# How can I retrieve a variable from Firebase and make it available as Global Variable to use it in other queries?

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to finish an app (Java and few classes in Kotlin) and I must give the option to the user switch between championships...

The ideia is that the user can create an championship and invite people to participate... but the user can participate of many championships and at any time the user must have an option to switch between championships...

The Firebase database looks like:

[image]

So I have to retrieve the key of the championship marked as true that is saved in the users node and then retrieve the information about the championship to display in the app.

```
        databaseReference?.child("usuarios")?.
            child("$keyuser")?.
            child("campeonatos")?.
            addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
                override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                    //Log.e("Count " ,""+dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount());
                    //for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    val children = dataSnapshot!!.children
                    children.forEach {
                        //println(it.toString())
                        if (it.value==true)
                        {
                            val keychamp = it.key
                        }
                    }
                }

                override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                    // Failed to read value
                }
            })
```

Note that in the code above the key of the user is $keyuser, now I have to put this code in somewhere and make $keychamp available to all classes so the data will be refreshed as soon as the user choose another championship in the app.

How can I make this variable $keychamp available to all classes in order to use it as a path to query and return the championship data?

Comment: How many championships can a user be registered to at a single time?

Comment: there are no limits... like groups of whatsapp... I hope one person will use this app for many and many championships!

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

I used SharedPreferences to make the variable available anytime I need. When the user wants to switch between championships it chooses one available and then the variable is updated using sharedpreferences. Look the code below!

First I set these global variables

```
val PREFS_FILENAME = "com.company.prefs"
var prefs: SharedPreferences? = null
```

Then I instantiated a SharedPreferences

```
prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
```

And finally I can change the value of the variable

```
val editor = prefs!!.edit()
editor.putString("keyChampionship", keyChampionship)
editor.apply()
```

As I am using Firebase I retrieve this variable and use it as the path to the node of the new championship!

```
val keyChampionship = prefs!!.getString("keyChampionship","DEFAULT")
```

Example of a reference created using this variable

```
val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/championship/$keyChampionship/matches")
```